# Class '\Laravel\Socialite\Two\TwitterProvider' not found Error

Tags: laravel, twitter-oauth, classnotfoundexception, laravel-socialite

I am doing some workaround to allow the user to link their social media account to our app as well as directly create an account using their social media accounts. 
I have followed this strategy [here](https://bosunski.fun/blog/How_to_use_multiple_callbacks_in_Laravel_Socialite/) for my linking of user's social media account for if I also use it in directly creating their accounts, I have a bunch of errors. So for now, the code works except for twitter for it returns the error:

> Class '\Laravel\Socialite\Two\TwitterProvider'

So in my web route, I have this:

```
// Link SNS
Route::post('/redirect/{provider}', 'User\SocialMediaController@linkMedia');
Route::get('/callback/link/{provider}', 'User\SocialMediaController@saveMedia')->name('socialLinkCallback');
```

In my SocialMediaController file, I have this:

```
use CanbuildSocialProvider;
/**
 *
 * link SNS
 *
 */
public function linkMedia(Request $request)
{
    $provider = $request->route('provider');
    $this->provider = $provider;
    $redirectUrl = url('/callback/link/' . $provider);

    return $this->buildSocialProvider($redirectUrl)->redirect();
}
```

And my twitter api settings, I have added already the callback url. This is the full error message displayed:

[image]

Please note that I have used the Traits provided on the link. In facebook and Google, the code works well except for the twitter. Does someone happen to know what is the cause for this one?

**UPDATE**

As what I have checked from `vendor>laravel>socialite>src>SocialiteManager.php`, Twitter is using `\Laravel\Socialite\One\AbstractProvider` while the others are using `\Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider`. Is there any way I can override it here:

```
public function buildSocialProvider(string $redirectUrl = null): ProviderInterface
{
    $providerClass = ucfirst($this->provider);
    $provider = strtoupper($this->provider);

    $config = [
        'client_id' => env($provider . '_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env($provider. '_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => $redirectUrl,
    ];

    return Socialite::buildProvider('\Laravel\Socialite\Two\\' . $providerClass . 'Provider', $config);
}
```

Comment: did you declare it below the namespace in the controller?

Comment: @BradGoldsmith As per my checking, Twitter is using `\Laravel\Socialite\One\\TwitterProvider` while the other SNS are using `\Laravel\Socialite\Two\\TwitterProvider` in `SocialiteManager.php` file, do you happen to know some way to resolve this twitter error?

Answer (score 0):

have you added the following to config/services.php, follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@Alabuja/social-login-in-laravel-with-socialite-90dbf14ee0ab

```
'twitter' => [
        'client_id'     => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect'      => env('TWITTER_URL'),
    ],
```

Comment: Have you added  TwitterProvider class to providers array in config/app.php